# cassandra disk growth is faster

Tags: cassandra, lsof

We have a cassandra docker cluster of 3 nodes, in one of the node the disk space is growing faster. But when we checked the nodetool status shows, it occupied only 561gb

```
 Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID  Rack  
UN  10.3.1.11  567.68 GB  256     ?       f67c30e0-b8be-4adb-a30c-7d4dc3b9d6b2  1b

UN  10.3.1.10  512.88 GB  256     ?       fb1cd75c-7ce8-4236-85f9-ef247c8fd89e  1b 

UN  10.3.1.12  **561.32** GB  256     ?       cc96f33e-0e51-47d6-8022-204de313aa50  1b
```

when we checked the file system, it shows 763GB occupied using df -hT command

```
/dev/xvdf       985G  763G  181G  81% /var/lib/cassandra.
```

we found some stale processes are still holding the space using the command lsof | grep '(deleted)'

We are not sure why there is  difference in diskspace shown using nodetool status and df -hT. Is there any issue with the cluster?

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra? How much space in saved caches and commitlog inside of /var/lib/cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

you can check snapshots files in data.There may be some snapshot files

Answer (score 0):

we have deleted large amount of backups before posting this. So some stale processes are still holding the space using the command lsof | grep '(deleted)'

We rebooted the server all the space got recovered